# Create DYLIB in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, dylib, shared-libraries

How to convert my libraryxxx.so to libraryxxx.dylib in Mac OSx via terminal?

I am currently using libraryxxx.so in my program but when I performed

otool -L myprogram.so

to show the list of libraries, libraryxxx.so wasn't included and only .dylib libraries were included.

Comment: `.so` files are not used by OS X, they are used by Linux and related systems. It's not possible to just "convert" an .so to a .dylib unless you have its source code.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Not quite true; have you looked in `/usr/lib/apache2`?  If the `.so` file works with `otool` then it's already a `.dylib` renamed with a `.so` file extension.  Simply rename it if necessary.

Comment: @trojanfoe well, yes, if it's a Mach-O dynamic library which appears to have the extension `.so`, then of course it will work -- it's not a matter of extension. But I'm sure you are getting it.